# NSView subclass for NSMenuItem

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I want to create a subview of NSView and link it to a MenuView.xib.

I'll have:

```
- MenuView.m
- MenuView.h
- MenuView.xib
```

in xcode I created my xib and set as customclass my 'MenuView'. Now I would like to add my new view programmatically via a command like this:

```
NSView *vv = [[MenuView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200)];

NSMenuItem *newItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
[newItem setView:vv];
```

but I just see an empty space without any content. How can I tell the class MenuView.m to render with the MenuView.xib file? Is that wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `NSViewController`, it's designed for loading views from a nib file. In your nib file, set `NSViewController` as the class of **File's Owner** and then set the `view` outlet of **File's Owner** so that it points to your view in the nib.

Then you can just do this:

```
NSViewController* viewController = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:nil];
YourCustomView* view = [viewController view]; //this loads the nib
[viewController release];
//do something with view
```

Answer (score 0):

To load a view from a nib (adapted from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884352/custom-outlets-in-nscollectionviewitem-subclass/7393215#7393215) of mine):

```
NSNib *nib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MenuView" bundle:nil];
NSArray *nibObjects;
if (![nib instantiateNibWithOwner:self topLevelObjects:&nibObjects]) return nil;

NSMenuItem *item = nil;

for (id obj in nibObjects)
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSMenuItem class]]) {
        item = obj;
        break;
    }

[someView insertSubview:item];
```

If you want something other than `self` as the file owner, change the parameter to `instantiateNibWithOwner:`.